# WAMP server is blocking shell_exec() in Windows?

Tags: php, apache, wamp, shell-exec

I can't use `shell_exec()` when using a WAMP server in Windows. I am using PHP 5.4+ so there is no safe mode, I have checked disabled functions, nothing is disabled. I simply get nothing from `shell_exec()`!

I have tried just doing echos on strings and I get it out normally.
Is there some way that WAMP or Apache is disabling my use of `shell_exec()`?

Comment: You would get an error if the function would somehow be "blocked". More likely is simply does not return any output. Have you checked your http servers error log file? That should always be the firs thing to do when being puzzled over an issue.